# Is it possible to create an Emacs package for the below mentioned use case with little Elisp knowledge?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, package

In my view, Emacs Org-Mode is the best task management tool. Nonetheless, I think it could be improved.

Each time I think of something that I should do, I create a todo in Org-Mode, so I now have almost 400 scheduled or unscheduled todo. I find it quite hard to review so many todo. For example, if I have free time someday, I need to be able to review these ~400 tasks in order to schedule some of them for this day. So I'd like to have some criteria helping me review these tasks, and I'd like the assessment of these criteria to be easily visible.

I thought of 3 criteria (ideally they would be customizable because maybe some other criteria are more useful for other people):

- Span (how long it would take to finish the task)
- Nice (is it horrible `▮` for me to do the task or very pleasant `▮▮▮▮▮▮`)
- Importance (assesses the negative consequences of not doing the task)

Here is how it could look like in `org-agenda`:

```
Unscheduled                                     Span    Nice    Importance
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Income tax declaration      ▮▮▮     ▮       ▮▮▮▮▮▮
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Beautify Emacs              ▮▮▮▮    ▮▮▮▮▮▮  ▮
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Buy Robot vacuum cleaner    ▮▮      ▮▮▮▮▮   ▮▮      
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Make 1h video on DS         ▮▮▮▮▮   ▮▮▮▮    ▮
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Repay Leo                   ▮       ▮▮▮▮▮▮  ▮
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Fix shelves in cellar       ▮▮▮     ▮▮      ▮
  ToDo:     BACKLOG Read Brothers Karamazov     ▮▮▮▮    ▮▮▮▮▮▮  ▮
```

Here is an example of a legend for the Span criteria:

```
▮ < 20 mn
▮▮ < 2 h
▮▮▮ < 1 day
▮▮▮▮ < 3 days
▮▮▮▮▮ < 7 days
▮▮▮▮▮▮ > 7 days
```

Comment: This kind of open-ended discussion question is better for a discussion site, such as Reddit. This site is more for *specific Q&A*, especially how-to questions.

Comment: You can implement all of these as properties. It then becomes "just" a matter of how to display them in the agenda.

Comment: I have nothing for your question, but I am pretty sure you want to take a look at Getting Things Done. There is an official site for that, as well as Wikipedia, but I usually like https://hamberg.no/gtd best as an intro. These kinds of questions ("how to find what to work on next") have kind of been solved in the last decades. ;) Once you have employed that system within your org file, keeping it up to date should be relatively quick and pain free (the system even works with pen&paper...). You'll find many results for "org-mode gtd" or "emacs gtd".

Comment: I already use GDT. Actually, it is because I was looking for a tool able to implement GDT that I discovered and started using Emacs and Org-Mode 10 years ago

Comment: *cheers* @crocefisso

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something that you can experiment with ....

1. Do `emacs -Q`
2. Copy the below snippet to `todo.org`
3. `C-x C-f todo.org`
4. Move to the `Tasks` headline and do `C-c C-x C-c` [Using column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-column-view.html) and you will see this

[image: Org Column View]
5. If you want an in buffer table, as opposed to table as overlay, move to the line that says [`#+BEGIN: columnview ...`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Column-View.html) and do `C-c C-c`.  You can then use `org-table-...` commands on the resulting table to sort the entries the way you want.

```
#+STARTUP: content

* Tasks
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       tasks
:SPAN_ALL: ▮ ▮▮ ▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮▮
:NICE_ALL: ▮ ▮▮ ▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE_ALL: ▮ ▮▮ ▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮▮
:COLUMNS: %30ITEM(TASK) %15SPAN(SPAN) %15NICE(NICE) %15IMPORTANCE(IMPORTANCE)
:END:

** TODO Income tax declaration
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮▮
:NICE:     ▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮▮▮▮▮▮
:END:

** TODO Beautify Emacs
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮▮▮
:NICE:     ▮▮▮▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮
:END:

** TODO Buy Robot vacuum cleaner
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮
:NICE:     ▮▮▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮▮
:END:

** TODO Make 1h video on DS
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮▮▮▮
:NICE:     ▮▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮
:END:

** TODO Repay Leo
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮
:NICE:     ▮▮▮▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮
:END:

** TODO Fix shelves in cellar
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮▮
:NICE:     ▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮
:END:

** TODO Read Brothers Karamazov
:PROPERTIES:
:STATE:    BACKLOG
:SPAN:     ▮▮▮▮
:NICE:     ▮▮▮
:IMPORTANCE: ▮▮▮▮▮
:END:

#+BEGIN: columnview :id tasks 
| TASK                     | SPAN  | NICE   | IMPORTANCE |
|--------------------------+-------+--------+------------|
| Tasks                    |       |        |            |
| Income tax declaration   | ▮▮▮   | ▮      | ▮▮▮▮▮▮     |
| Beautify Emacs           | ▮▮▮▮  | ▮▮▮▮▮▮ | ▮          |
| Buy Robot vacuum cleaner | ▮▮    | ▮▮▮▮▮  | ▮▮         |
| Make 1h video on DS      | ▮▮▮▮▮ | ▮▮▮▮   | ▮          |
| Repay Leo                | ▮     | ▮▮▮▮▮▮ | ▮          |
| Fix shelves in cellar    | ▮▮▮   | ▮▮     | ▮          |
| Read Brothers Karamazov  | ▮▮▮▮  | ▮▮▮    | ▮▮▮▮▮      |
#+END:

# Local Variables:
# coding: utf-8
# End:
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. It made me discover `org-set-property` (`C-c C-x p`). Do you think it would be possible to tweak `org-set-property`, so that when you input `5` as a value, `▮▮▮▮▮`is written?

Comment: Or when you have `5` written, `org-agenda` / `columnview` shows `▮▮▮▮▮`.

Comment: I have updated my previous response a bit ... It now includes `_ALL` property.  Just do a `C-c C-x p` and then pick the signal level interactively.  (It helps if you have any of the completion frameworks like `helm`, `vertico` etc installed)  See `(info "(org) Property Syntax")` or [Property Syntax (The Org Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Property-Syntax.html)

Comment: You can use `S-<RIGHT>` and `S-<LEFT>` to increase/decrease the signal levels. Read the manual page I linked to.

Comment: I didn't know about [column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Column-View.html). With this functionality, no need to build a package to tweak `org-agenda`.

Comment: I have updated  my ealier respons with a screenshot of `Column View`.  If you are in `Column View`, you can press `3` and get the property updated.    I want to get you excited.  So I encourgage you to read the manual and experiment more.  For example, if you do `M-x customize-group org-properties`, I see stuff like `Org Columns Default Format For Agenda `.  There is also a summary type (which is a derived value of a property).  Yes, my gut feeling suggests that what you hope to do is possible without writing elisp or with minimal elisp.  Good luck.

Comment: Look at `org-properties-postprocess-alist` where a derived property `Remaining` is calculated based on `Effort`.  I suppose you can translate numbers like `3` etc to three numbers of `bar`s etc.

Comment: Your implementation of the proposed use case is almost perfect. The only missing feature that I'm facing now is the inability to sort columns by value. And this is due to the nature of the value (`▮`). Do you see a way to solve this (without losing the advantage of having an insightful visual)?

Comment: Or maybe it is not related with the (`▮`) since I have the following message: `sort-subr: Text is read-only: #("Type ‘e’ to edit property" 6 7 (face help-key-binding font-lock-face help-key-binding))Invalid face attribute :bold t`

Comment: So it appears that view column needs to modify the todo file to sort a column... Couldn't it only do the sort in view mode without changing the file?

Comment: [Here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html#:~:text=First%20press%20C%2Dc%20C%2Dx%20C%2Dc,displaying%20some%20of%20its%20properties.) is a nice intro to colomn view. To set column view, I added `(setq org-columns-default-format "%70ITEM(TODOs) %1PRIORITY %8SPAN(SPAN) %8NICE(BLISS) %8IMPORTANCE(IMPACT)")` to my init. And I added `#+PROPERTY: SPAN_ALL ▮ ▮▮ ▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮▮ ▮▮▮▮▮▮` etc. at the beginning of each todo file.